# Django: How to insert variable into path() kwargs

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to pass a boolean flag to my view:

```
def lesson_detail_view(request, number, **kwargs):
    pass
```

The documentation has an example of passing in kwargs, but only as hard coded.

```
path('blog/<int:year>/', views.year_archive, {'foo': 'bar'})
```

My problem is getting the variable into the url pattern.
I've tried to insert a variable the same way the path variables work with angle brackets, but it's not working.

```
path('lesson-<number>/', views.lesson_detail_view, kwargs={'show_popup': '<show_popup>'}, name='lesson_detail'),
```

The following is how I want to call the url:

```
redirect("lesson:lesson_detail", number=1, show_popup=True,)
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree? I feel like this should be pretty straight forward, but I'm not finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the <show_popup> to be provided by the user? If so you should look into using get parameters.
In the view you would access get parameters using

```
request.GET.get('show_popup', None)
```

If you want to put a variable from where the urls.py file into the view:

```
path('lesson-<number>/', views.lesson_detail_view, kwargs={'show_popup': show_popup}, name='lesson_detail')
```

Comment: I've got the view all taken care of. Just need to get the url figured out.

Comment: Now that you added the path, I'll comment on that. Adding show_popup as you did will not work. It would throw a NameError because show_popup is not defined in the url file.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do then?
Before my edit I had assumed you wanted to pass something from the url like so
lesson-1/?show_popup=true

Comment: I don't want to put it in the get params. Just want to pass it in the kwargs if possible. In other words the url should be still be '/lesson-1/', but be able to get the show_popup flag in the view it calls'

Comment: Where would the variable be coming from exactly?